# How to create an Angular UI Bootstrap Accordion Group with no body?

Tags: angularjs, accordion, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm quite happy with the Angular UI Bootstrap Accordion, but I encountered a problem when creating a Accordion Group with no body. The Accordion will always create an empty body and I couldn't find a way to prevent this. Is there a way to prevent the creation of the accordion body or can the accordion group be created in a way that it is not expandable?

[Plunker with example](http://plnkr.co/edit/X55ej586U89cLFgqX7mA?p=preview)

Comment: Just wondering why you'd want an accordion with no content in it. Perhaps you could use the `ui.bootstrap.collapse` directive, that's more customizable than the accordion directive.

Comment: I am using the accordion to display financial results. The details for specific sections are collapsible, but some entries just don't have details. I will have a look at the collapse directive and see how I get the same functionality.

Answer (score 1):

**Accordion Directive**

> The accordion directive builds on top of the collapse directive to
>   provide a list of items, with collapsible bodies that are collapsed or
>   expanded by clicking on the item's header.

As I stated in the comment, just use the Collapse directive and style it like an accordion.

**Update:**

Not styled to perfection but try this

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="CollapseDemoCtrl">
  <div class="accordion-group" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle">Group with body</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div collapse="!isCollapsed" class="collapse">
    <div class="well well-large">Some content</div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
function CollapseDemoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.isCollapsed = false;
}
```

**[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/sm1J9FFwZ4adrcneWRQx?p=preview)**

Comment: I tried it, but in the plunkr the accordion group without body still collapses the empty body. I ended up just using the divs of the accordion-group to get the same stiling, but without any Angular code attached to it.